# Firefox New Tab Top Sites Icon Background Color

Tags: html, css, firefox, customization

### Background

**Operating System**: Windows 10, 64-Bit
**Firefox Version**: 84.0.2, 64-Bit

I have recently made a [modification](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1271362) to my Firefox profile to allow the New Tab page to have a background image, but now I am noticing some strange behavior.

When first running Firefox it looks like this:
[image: Firefox New Tab Top Sites Icon Background Transparent]

As you can see, for the sites that don't have a high-quality favicon available, Firefox uses a letter and the low-quality favicon. What I'm pointing out here is that the background for these is transparent.

However, when I open some sites and navigate around, I come back to see this:
[image: Firefox New Tab Top Sites Icon Background White]

There is now no visible letter and the background color for these icons have changed to white. I cannot seem to reproduce this, it just eventually happens after regular use.

This can be fixed by closing the browser and reopening it, but obviously, that's an inconvenience.

### Question

Is there a way I can force the icon backgrounds to be transparent, or at least change the solid color to something more fitting to the theme? If possible, please let me know if there is a reason this is happening.

*Note: If you require more information please feel free to ask.*

### Edit 1

I would rather not resort to setting a custom thumbnail for each of these because I like the way Firefox handles it by default. I'm just looking to fix the *ugly* white background that comes out of nowhere.

Comment: this looks like a bug in Firefox. Have you considered [filing a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Firefox&component=New%20Tab%20Page) for the New Tab?

Comment: @Dexter I have not, however, I will take this into consideration if a solution is not found here in a reasonable time. Thanks for the suggestion!